# Driver needed for wireless adapter WNA3100

Tags: networking, broadcom

As many questions before me, I am trying to get Netgear's WNA3100 to work on my Ubuntu machine.

I googled, I searched the forum, turns out the link everyone points to to get the actual driver is dead. :(

Does anybody have another source to find the Broadcom_bcm43xx_USB_32_64bit_v2 file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I recommend the *amended* version.

Here is a link to a copy on my personal Dropbox: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58267392/Broadcom_bcm43xx_USB_32_64bit_v2_amended.zip